# How to get plain text inside body tag using dom..and get the words into an array?

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to get the contents inside body tag..seperate them as words and get the words into an array..am using php
This is what i have done

```
$content=file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);
$content=html_entity_decode($content);
$content = preg_replace("/&#?Ã[a-z0-9]+;/i"," ",$content); 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$tags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach($tags as $h)
{
echo "<li>".$h->tagName;
 getChilds2($h);    

function getChilds2($node)
{

  if($node->hasChildNodes())
   { 
   foreach($node->childNodes as $c)
    { 
        if($c->nodeType==3)
         {

           $nodeValue=$c->nodeValue;   
            $words=feature_node($c,$nodeValue,true);
           if($words!=false)
             {
              $_ENV["words"][]=$words;

             } 

             else if($c->tagName!="")
             {


             getChilds2($c);  
              }
        }
      }

   }
  else
  {
   return;
  }
}
function feature_node($node,$content,$display)
{

 if(strlen($content)<=0)
  {
   return;
   }

 $content=strtolower($content);
 $content=mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
      mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
    $content= drop_script_tags($content);       
$temp=$content;
$content=strip_punctuation($content);
$content=strip_symbols($content);
$content=strip_numbers($content);
$words_after_noise_removal=mb_split( ' +',$content);
$words_after_stop_words_removal=remove_stop_words($words_after_noise_removal);
if(count($words_after_stop_words_removal)==0)
 return(false);
$i=0;
foreach($words_after_stop_words_removal as $w)
   {

      $words['word'][$i]=$w;
      $i++;
   }

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($words['word']);$i++)
 { 
   $words['stemmed'][$i]= PorterStemmer::Stem($words['word'][$i],true)."<br/>";
 }

 return($words);
}
```

Here i have used some functions like strip_punctuation,strip_symbols,strip_numbers,remove stop_words and porterstemmer for preprocessing of the page..they ar eworking fine..but am not getting the contents into array and print_r() or echo gives nothing..help plz?

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to to iterate over the nodes.

```
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
```

will give you just one result in the DOMNodeList.  So all you need to do to get the text is

```
$plainText = $tags->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

or

```
$plainText = $tags->item(0)->textContent;
```

To get the separate words into an array, you can use

- [`str_word_count` — Return information about words used in a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

on the resulting `$plainText` then